# Javascript to have a fixed navbar is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

http://www.new.techmoney360.com/ is the website and it's being developed with wordpress.

That navigarion bar is part of the `<header>` that also encompass my logo section up top so I'm not sure if that causing issues.

This is the entire html the encompasses the navigation bar that I want to stick to the top when I scroll past it.

```
<div  id="navmenu" class="mkd-menu-area">
    <div class="mkd-grid">
        <div class="mkd-vertical-align-containers">
            <div class="mkd-position-left">
                <div class="mkd-position-left-inner">
                    <?php if(is_active_sidebar('mkd-left-from-main-menu')) : ?>
                        <?php dynamic_sidebar('mkd-left-from-main-menu'); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php discussion_get_main_menu(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mkd-position-right">
                <div class="mkd-position-right-inner">
                    <?php if(is_active_sidebar('mkd-right-from-main-menu')) : ?>
                        <?php dynamic_sidebar('mkd-right-from-main-menu'); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the javascript I'm using to target the navigation bar (thanks to [akinuri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2202732/akinuri) for the script)

```
window.onscroll = changePos;

function changePos() {
   var header = document.getElementById("navmenu");
   if (window.pageYOffset > 182) {
      header.style.position = "absolute";
      header.style.top = pageYOffset + "px";
   } else {
      header.style.position = "";
      header.style.top = "";
   }
}
```

Comment: don't need javascript, just css: #navmenu{position:fixed}

Comment: @Jacob - OP wants it to stick when it has scrolled a bit, not always.

Comment: Has nobody noticed the two javascript errors being thrown on the site, which are (probably) the cause of at least part of the problem?

Comment: @cale_b if you're referring to a javascript that's related to something of the sort of "sticky-nav" I know what that is and it's the sticky nav that came with the template that I nuked. It's an easy fix. Otherwise I have no idea what else it could be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jacob is partially correct, you don't need (as much) JavaScript here. Here's how you can resolve the issue. Replace the current functionality with this:

```
window.onscroll = stickyNav;

function stickyNav() {
   var header = document.getElementById("navmenu");
   if (window.pageYOffset > 70) {
      header.classList.add("sticky");
   } else {
      header.classList.remove("sticky");
   }
}
```

Then, create a new class called `.sticky` with the following styling adjustments:

```
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Edit: update `stickNav` to `stickyNav`.

Comment: hmmm. I see what you're doing here but that doesn't seem to work for some reason.

Comment: I edited it a bit to include a space in the `if` className addition, which might have caused an issue. See if that helps. Otherwise, let me know what issues you're seeing.

Comment: I added you're edit with the space before sticky (I copy pasted you're whole changes) and nothing changed. The navbar doesn't get fixed anymore at all. 

Where as the javascript I was using before worked it just made the bar all messy looking. 

I understad what you doing and I see how it's more proper.

Comment: I'm seeing console errors regarding the updates you added, which might have something to do with it: `ReferenceError: stickNav is not defined`, `TypeError: mysticky_navbar is null`. It's hard to do much without direct access to the code, but play around. This is much better for performance.

Comment: mysticky_navbar was a plugin I removed. 
the second error I found was with your code. windows.onscroll = stickNav needs to be stickyNav, that being said it still doesn't work so I'm still trying to figure it out. It seems the custom css won't apply when scrolling

Comment: I was wrong. It does apply the css, and it does this: mkd-menu-area .sticky .sticky .sticky .sticky .sticky .sticky .sticky .sticky .sticky .sticky .sticky .sticky .sticky .sticky .sticky .sticky .sticky .sticky .sticky .sticky .sticky .sticky .sticky .sticky .sticky .sticky .sticky .sticky .sticky .sticky

Comment: Good catch! I just noticed that as well. Apologies, I'm used to using jQuery for adding / removing class names via `addClass`. I'll edit again to use JavaScript `classList`, just to get things working! Here's a good reference for extending the `classList` functionality, if needed: http://gomakethings.com/ditching-jquery-for-vanilla-js/

Comment: fiddling around with the numbers in your answer got exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much :)

ps, `classList.add` does not work. All I did to solve it was just hardcoded it in with `header.className = "mkd-menu-area sticky";` if it was the right to do I am not sure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113565/discussion-between-robolisk-and-ghost-dad).

Answer (score 2):

Place `.mkd-top-bar` outside of all wrappers and whatnot, place it below the `<body>` and in it's css apply `position: fixed;`

```
.mkd-top-bar {
    background-color: #303030;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: that's a part of it, it was actually going to be my next challenge to do. 
Currently I'm just trying to get my navigation menu/bar to stick to the top and that's what the post is mostly relating to

Comment: Ah okay, I'd edit my answer however I believe [ghost_dad Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37576987/6410837) should do the trick